# Electromagnetic Radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

If there was a way to see the electromagnetic waves that is all around us, i.e. see the electric and magnetic fields spreading away from an antenna say, how would it look? I mean if we were to freeze the picture to a single instant of time, and somehow construct a 3D diagram of the spreading electromagnetic disturbance how would it look. Considering that in nature, a change in electric flux creates a change in magnetic flux and vice versa and they sustain each other as they spread out, how would the picture look? starting from a single circle of electric field, would it create infinite circles of magnetic field perpendicular to itself around its circular periphery and those magnetic fields in turn give rise to infinite circular electric fields around themselves? This is a poor explanation possibly but the point is just how the EM wave propagates and how it looks like in reality?

Comment: You never had a look into a textbook or in wikipedia? I think You look for some chat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the diagrams of electromagnetic waves](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20331/)

Answer (score 1):

It would "look" just like the electromagnetic waves you do see.  Photons in the visible spectrum are the same as photons in the radio spectrum, they just have different wavelengths.  If you want a rigorous description of a quantitative phenomenon, you'll have to be more specific, but there are plenty of them out there if you look around.

Comment: I think there are two things here that I've mixed up. First, is this idea about EM energy propagation correct? - For a propagating EM wave: an electric field induces a magnetic field (Maxwell's law of induction), and the induced magnetic field induces yet another electric field (Faraday's law of induction) and so on and the wave propagates through space one field creating the other and so forth. I can see how time varying fields are induced in the immediate space about an accelerating charge, but I'm unable to understand how these fields travel through space spreading out from the source.

Comment: The second question is to do with what I meant by "look".. I didn't mean "look" as in how we see EM energy in the visible spectrum by our eyes for instance.. Consider this hypothetical setup: A room filled with positive test charges arranged in a uniform fashion (a 3D closely packed grid) say we place an oscillating charge in the center of the room as our EM source. the test charges would start wiggling as they feel the force of the EM wave pass through them).. What would be the path traced out by each of these wiggling test charges look like as they are influenced by the traveling EM wave?

Comment: The source of EM can also imagined to be some antenna like an isotropic antenna that radiates in all directions!

Comment: In electromagnetic field theory, wave fronts like those produced by a radio antenna are considered plane waves. On the scale of individual photons, though, the picture is totally different. The 'detail' of the image you are looking for depends on your paradigm. You have to pick one (moving test charge and plane waves) or the other (electric and magnetic fields of a photon).

Comment: I guess I was referring to the test charge and plane waves model then..

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_waves

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent tool for "visualising" the electric and magnetic fields of waves being produced by a variety of sources (including antennae). This applet allows you to slow down time or even freeze it at a particular instant. You can show the fields, but also the rate of change of the fields and the currents. What is doesn't do is show this in full 3-D, you have to us a bit of imagination here, but I find these simulations very useful and so do my students.

http://www.falstad.com/emwave1/