# What is the electric field part of an EM wave? Radiation field or the induction field?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, terminology, electric-fields

Look at this image:

[image: Electromagnetic wave]

I wonder if the electric field is from the induction field from a vibrating electron or the radiation field? If it is from the radiation field, as I suppose, than can someone explain why they are perpendicular to me? As they have derived it from [this link](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/Why%20an%20Antenna%20Radiates.pdf). It says that the magnetic field and the radiation field is in phase(in degrees! not in x-direction).

Comment: Hi user7773, I think your question is already answered in http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20331/understanding-the-diagrams-of-electromagnetic-waves/.

Comment: Nja, not really. It just mention the electric field. Not how it is perpendicular.

Comment: This can be a simple plane electromagnetic wave in a vacuum, thus no electrons.  There need not be a medium for these to exist.