# Do light particles come in different sizes?

Tags: particle-physics, photons

Do light particles come in different sizes if it makes sense to even think about them that way?

Comment: I feel like this has been asked recently

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74316/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Size of Photon?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206772/)

Comment: Or one of the [other many questions previously asked on this matter](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3aq%20size%20photon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense to think of light particles having size.  The picture of light as a particle in the everyday sense is a metaphor to give us language to talk about light and its interactions.  Like all metaphors and analogies, the idea eventually breaks down.  The metaphorical object (particle in this case) has properties that the actual thing does not have.  That's what we have here:  a push of the metaphor beyond its usefulness.

Answer (score -1):

Like other people said, it doesn't make sense to think of the size of photons. It is irrevelant really. All we can say about light particles is its frequency. The greater the frequency, the bigger the energy the photon carries.