# Two possible directions of the B field in relation to the E field in radio waves. How induce the left-handed direction?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, elementary-particles

In vacuum the two field components of a radio wave are directed perpendicular on each over. $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ form a right hand system ($\mathbf{k}$ is the direction of propagation).

[image]

[Source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411500/shape-of-electromagnetic-wave/411511#411511)

This matches the right hand rule for a current carrying wire and the induces magnetic field around the wire.

Now, for the reasons of symmetry, a radio wave also could be drawn with $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{-B}$ and $\mathbf{k}$. Aplicated to the image above, the green fieldlines (which showing the direction of the magnetic field) simply would show in the opposite direction. How induce a left hand radio wave?

Comment: *left-handed meta materials* do just that.  They are the topic of much current research.

Comment: Closely related question by the same user: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461167/44126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such symmetry argument ?

If you change $\overrightarrow{B}\to -\overrightarrow{B}$ and $\overrightarrow{E}\to \overrightarrow{E}$ the Maxwell Faraday equation $\overrightarrow{\nabla }\wedge \overrightarrow{E}=-\frac{\partial \overrightarrow{B}}{\partial t}$ would not be true anymore.

Comment: Vincent, that seems to be another formulaton of my question. Furthermore, the current is from electrons. What about a current of protons (in a vacuum tube for example) or a current from positrons?

Comment: The charge does not interfere with Maxwell Faraday's equation. I think the wave you propose can not be a solution of Maxwell's equations (and therefore does not exist) because it cannot check Maxwell Faraday's equation.